# doesn't know a type (casting)

Tags: c++

I want to add a variable in a message header so I used `unit8_t` to define them but when I want to read this variable I need to cast it in double I did:

```
hello.positionx = unit8_t (m_ipv4->GetObject<MobilityModel> ()->GetPosition ().x);   
hello.positiony = unit8_t (m_ipv4->GetObject<MobilityModel> ()->GetPosition ().y);
```

as you can see these lines are similar but when I run my program it shows an error in second line which : `unit8_t` in not defined in this scope
I added the Header :

```
 #include"stdint.h"
```

I don't know, what's the meaning of this error. I will be thankful if you help me .

Answer (score 6):

The name of the type is `uint8_t`, which stands for "unsigned integer, 8 bits wide". You seem to have mistyped it.

Comment: yes exactly, I checked all my program but didn't pay attention to it. thanks

Comment: Nit pick:  `uint8_t` is an "unsigned 8-bit integer"